# Dynamics CRM - Stamp out new Org, Build / Deploy Plugins all from MSBUILD - Issues

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, msbuild-task

I'm getting a run time exception in my deployed, exported, and then imported to another box... CRM Solution.  The Exception is:

`System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'`

It only occurs when I use a MSBUILD script to do this.  When I use VS (2010) by hand to do this, all is well.  So, first suspect is my script.  My script uses a MSBUILD custom task, inspired by http://fczaja.blogspot.com/2012/07/continuous-integration-with-crm.html.

My sense is the issue could be on the Export step - which uses the `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy`, up-cast to `IOrganizationService.Execute`, passing an `ExportSolutionRequest` object.  We set the `SolutionName` and `Managed` properties only.  Perhaps we're missing another property?

I'm trying to narrow it's root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you by any chance using ILMerge on your plugin assembly?

If so I suspect it is an issue with your reference assemblies, perhaps having .NET 4.5 on the build server but not on the machine where you build it manually.

These links will explain futher if this is indeed the case:
http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2012/02/29/What-you-should-know-about-running-ILMerge-on-Net-45-Beta-assemblies-targeting-Net-40.aspx

The fundamental fix is to change your ILMerge reference assemblies to be -/targetplatform:"v4,C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0"

Comment: Ben - Thanks.  We are indeed using ILMerge and had recently added VS 2012 to the build machine.  Yes, a colleague had also pointed mt o the discussion at [link]
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748055/could-not-load-type-system-runtime-compilerservices-extensionattribute-from-as) and the answer there.

Note that as in your example, referencing the "Program Files (x86)" directory instead of the "Program Files" is important.