# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 roll up 12 with .net 4.5 Framework

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, .net-4.5, crm

Is Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 roll up 12 is Supporting .net 4.5 Framework.Will there be issue with Plugin workflows.

Comment: If you are using ILMerge as part of your build process it is worth looking as this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470385/dynamics-crm-stamp-out-new-org-build-deploy-plugins-all-from-msbuild-issu/14558298#14558298

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, after roll up 8, MSCRM 2011 currently supports .Net 4.5 for plugin development.

[Microsoft Dynamics CRM Compatibility List](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3005163/compatibility-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011)

```
Product            | Minimum CRM Version | CRM Build Number | Status
.Net Framework 4.0 | RTM                 | 5.0.9688.583     | Compatible 
.Net Framework 4.0 | PU3                 |                  | TBD 
.Net Framework 4.5 | Update Rollup 8     | 5.0.9690.2243    | Compatible
```

Comment: Tanks. I will create a plugin and check after deployment.