# Is an ILMerged assembly inherently incompatible with Mono?

Tags: mono, ilmerge

I've found many blog posts mentioning that ILMerge only works on Windows, and a couple that seem to suggest that ILMerged assemblies only work on Windows.

I don't care about actually running ILMerge in Mono, I'm just interested in using the merged assembly under Mono; has anyone successfully done this?

thanks!

Comment: You may also be interested in an opensource replacement for ILMerge and MonoMerge, [ILRepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've verified that ILMerged assemblies will run under Mono.  It was necessary to update the ILMerge command line option to:

```
/targetplatform:&quot;v4,C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0&quot;
```

(as described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748055/could-not-load-type-system-runtime-compilerservices-extensionattribute-from-as))