# Why does my ToolkitScriptManager keep failing on IIS 7.5? (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an ASP.NET website that uses AjaxControlToolkit. Everything works great when running locally, and even when I first publish it to my IIS server but after a while (could be 30 minutes or a couple of days) it will eventually fail and give me the error

```
The requested script resource 'Common.Common.js' requires version 
'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.725, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' of the ASP.NET AJAX Framework.
To use this resource, make sure that the application references 
version 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.725, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e'.
```

I've tried reinstalling ajax via visual studio package manager. I've even downloaded a stand alone copy and referenced the dll that way. 
My web config has the assembly

`add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.725, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"`

and my page control references it as well

controls

`add tagPrefix="asp" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.725, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"`
 controls

I would like to point out that if I use script manager everything works great except my auto complete extender stops working. It seems like it has something to do with ToolkitScriptManager.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My dev computer has .net 4.5 on it while my production server is at 4.0.

It didn't matter that i set the target framework to 4.0 because of the changes made in 4.5 preventing ILMerge from correctly merging the assemblies.

More information in this post

[Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748055/could-not-load-type-system-runtime-compilerservices-extensionattribute-from-as)