# .NET-Framework Mismatch 4.0.1/4.5 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute'

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, workflow-foundation

A rehosted Workflow Foundation Designer throws an exception while loading a workflow.

The following exception is thrown:

> System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException: 'Failed to create a 'Settings'
>   from the text 'Assembly references and imported namespaces for
>   internal implementation'.' Line number '1' and line position '135'.
>
> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly
>   'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

This exception appears only on systems with .NET 4.0 Update 1 installed. On computers having .NET 4.5 installed there is no problem at all.

The problem seens to be that 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' was moved in .NET 4.5 to mscorlib.dll (formerly located in System.Core.dll).

I have no clue, why it is just searching in mscorlib.dll and not in System.Core.dll as it should in a .NET 4.0 environment.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748055/could-not-load-type-system-runtime-compilerservices-extensionattribute-from-as)

Comment: Solved this problem. Cause of this bug was not mentioned in bug description. In Designer Activities were loaded from Assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.dll". This Assembly was taken from Visual Studio 2012 ==> which based on .NET 4.5. Many thanks to all who read this report and thought about it.