# .net 4.0.3 On Windows 8? Is it possible

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-8, windows-8.1

I just formatted my computer not even a week ago after being on Win 7 for a long time. I thought it was safe as at work I been using Windows for like a year now and have not had to go to load Windows 7 up since switching.

Now I just got a project that is apparently set to .net 4.0.3 version and won't be upgraded at this time.

I tried downloading .net 4.0.3 on Windows 8 but it always fails for me. I get

[image]

"KB2600211 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer."

I thought maybe if I install VS 2010(as they want me to use VS 2010 becuase they are a bit worried VS 2012 will do something funky to the project and mess everyone else on the team who are on Windows 7 and Vs 2010).

Anyone know how I can get at least 4.0.3 on windows 8? I don't want to format, took so long to get up to speed and won't be able to do Win Phone 8 programming anymore.

I would also have to stick it on my other HDD as my SDD can't fit both OS on with VS on it. So I will have a very slow OS and very fast OS.

Comment: Why do you think it is necessary to install 4.0.3?

Comment: @HansPassant  - Because it told me to.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the installed .NET Framework version.  You just lost the reference assemblies when you installed Windows 8, the update renamed your original program files directory.  Just put them back by installing the [.NET 4.0.3 multi-targeting pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29052)

Comment: @HansPassant is right. Same situation with Windows 10 (has pre-installed .NET 4.6) - I had to install **.NET 4.0.3 multi-targeting pack** to be able to target .NET 4.0 with my VS2010

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that .net 4.5 is an in-place install which *replaces* .net 4.0.  You cannot have both installed at the same time and Windows 8 comes pre-installed with .net 4.5. For the most part you should be able to just use .net 4.5 as if it were .net 4.0 but there are some breaking changes.  You might be able to uninstall 4.5 and then install 4.0, but that sounds rather risky.

At a previous job, we didn't upgrade to .net 4.5 for exactly this reason.  Until everyone is upgrading at the same time, there can be substantial compatibility issues.

For a list of incompatibility issues see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Note that this doesn't cover any places where your app may have been depending on a bug in .net 4.0 which is now fixed in 4.5 or any things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13750130/901059) where a type is moved to a different assembly (these are not considered breaking changes, so they aren't listed in the incompatibility list).

Comment: hmm that sucks, if I have .net 4.5 on Windows can I get back to 4.0?

Comment: On Win 7 sure, on Win 8 I don't know how that would work since 4.5 comes pre-installed.  I poked around a bit and some people claimed they did it, but it sounds like a terrible idea to me.

Comment: Sigh guess I can't escape windows 7 and have to go through all this trouble now with dual boot