# ILMerge : predefined type defined in multiples assemblies

Tags: c#, dll, assemblies, ilmerge

I have 3 C# projects in my Visual Studio solution :

`project1` : Class library in .NET4

`project2` : Class library in .NET4 with Microsoft.Bcl.Asyn NuGet package.

`projectFinal` : Console application in .NET5

The `project3` references `project2` and `project2` references `project1`. I wan't to hide the `project1.dll` to `project3`.

So I launch the ILMerge command :

```
ILMerge /target:libray project2.dll  project1.dll  /out:project12.dll  /internalize /lib:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

Compilation and merge are OK, I can reference `project12.dll` in my `project3`. But I have lots of warning :

```
The predefined type 'System.Action' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'project12.dll'
```

or

```
The predefined type 'System.Func' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'project12.dll'
```

How can I resolve my problem during compilation/merge ?

Comment: Have you tried the /allowDup argument to ILMerge?

Comment: That's [pretty doubtful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748055/could-not-load-type-system-runtime-compilerservices-extensionattribute-from-as/13750130#13750130).  .NET 5???

Comment: That was .NET4.5 sorry

Comment: But when I use ILMerge with AllowDup, I have the error : Additional information: Could not load type 'ProgressHandler' from assembly 'A.B.C, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method 'func' has no implementation (no RVA).