# ASP.NET MVC 4 Website won't start - Could not load type 'System.Reflection.AssemblyMetadataAttribute'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webactivator

I deployed my ASP.NET MVC 4 web app to a Windows Server 2003 (IIS 6). But it will not start.

Originally I had developed the project for .NET 4.5, but had to rebuild it for .NET4 when I found out that .NET 4.5 is not supported on Windows Server 2003. 
This meant removing all the third party references (with NuGet), changing the build target in project properties to .NET4, then adding the references back.
The references were to Ninject, EF and Automapper.

When I try to load a page I get the following error:

> Could not load type 'System.Reflection.AssemblyMetadataAttribute' from
>   assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.  Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'System.Reflection.AssemblyMetadataAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'System.Reflection.AssemblyMetadataAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.]
>   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken,
>   IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs,
>   Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
>   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module,
>   Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +180
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken,
>   Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) +192
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord
>   caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly,
>   RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken,
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[]
>   attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType,
>   IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean&
>   isVarArg) +115
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule
>   decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount,
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList
>   derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +426 
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, RuntimeType caType) +103
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type
>   attributeType, Boolean inherit) +64
>   WebActivator.AssemblyExtensions.GetActivationAttributes(Assembly
>   assembly) +113
>   WebActivator.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods() +216
>   WebActivator.ActivationManager.RunPreStartMethods() +28
>   WebActivator.ActivationManager.Run() +55
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization
>   method Run on type WebActivator.ActivationManager threw an exception
>   with the following error message: Could not load type
>   'System.Reflection.AssemblyMetadataAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'..] 
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1
>   methods) +423
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +306
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +677
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization
>   method Run on type WebActivator.ActivationManager threw an exception
>   with the following error message: Could not load type
>   'System.Reflection.AssemblyMetadataAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'..] 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9164848 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
>   +258

Any ideas?

EDIT: Website developed using VS2012

Comment: OK so I think I found the answer based on this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20227810/164297 looks like I'll be uninstalling .NET 4.5 from my machine

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748055/could-not-load-type-system-runtime-compilerservices-extensionattribute-from-as)

Answer (score 1):

```
Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly mscorlib
```

Yes, this technically can go wrong when you execute code on .NET 4.0 instead of .NET 4.5. The attribute was moved from System.Core.dll to mscorlib.dll in .NET 4.5. While that sounds like a rather nasty breaking change in a framework version that is supposed to be 100% compatible, a [TypeForwardedTo] attribute is supposed to make this difference unobservable.