# Can't add reference to .NET Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, openstreetmap

I'm trying to build the OsmSharp latest download from their GIT repo.
https://osmsharp.codeplex.com/

The problem is that I try and build and get a load of errors.  The main one seems to be

> "Error    296 Cannot define a new extension method because the compiler
>   required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute'
>   cannot be found. Are you missing a reference to System.Core.dll?"

This is a Portable Class Library and so I try to add the reference by right-clicking on the project and choosing "Add Reference", choosing .NET and I have nothing to add!

Anyone any ideas on how to get a list of .NET references to add?

[image]

Comment: it would be `browse`'s tab instead

Comment: Where would I browse the reference from?

I always expect .NET references to be internal things from the framework and not like a DLL I need to manually add.

Comment: Sorry I misread it , I thought you wanted to reference the DLL you built

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748055/could-not-load-type-system-runtime-compilerservices-extensionattribute-from-as.

Comment: Thanks for the link, this machine doesn't have .NET 4.5 installed however so that doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: @AdamantUK, Same issue. did u resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because there weren't any Target Frameworks set in the Library section of the project properties. Adding a couple fixed the issue.