# Issue when using ILMerge to merge .NET 3.5 & .NET 2.0 assemblies

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, ilmerge

When attempting to merge several assemblies in a VS Post Build I ran into the issue:

```
ILMerge version 2.13.307.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2004-2006. All rights reserved.
ILMerge /out:Assembly.dll AssemblyA.dll AssemblyB.dll /targetplatform:v2,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5 /log:log.txt 
Set platform to 'v2', using directory 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5' for mscorlib.dll
An exception occurred during merging:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Compiler.Class' to type 'System.Compiler.Struct'.
   at System.Compiler.SystemTypes.Initialize(Boolean doNotLockFile, Boolean getDebugInfo, PostAssemblyLoadProcessor postAssemblyLoad)
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
```

where AssemblyA is the current project output $(TargetFileName) and AssemblyB is a referenced assembly.

1. AssemblyA => v3.5
2. AssemblyB => v2.0

The weird thing is that when I change the command to use .NET 4 it works:

```
ILMerge /out:Assembly.dll AssemblyA.dll AssemblyB.dll /targetplatform:v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 /log:log.txt
```

Since I wish the merged assembly to be version 3.5 and not 4 how do I get the former command to work or how do I resolve this error?

Comment: Use the proper directory for mscorlib, c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727.  .NET 3.5 is not a new runtime version.  Beware that your v4 command line is [dangerously wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13750130/17034).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @HansPassant. I will change the first command from v3.5 to 2... Would you mind telling me how the v4 command line is dangerously wrong?

Comment: @HansPassant If you want to be credited for providing the correct solution please post your response as an answer.

Comment: I don't know if that was a correct answer.  Did it solve the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> using directory 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5' for mscorlib.dll

Have a look, that directory doesn't contain mscorlib.dll.  There is not much there at all, the .NET Framework versions 3.0, 3.5 and 3.5SP1 do not include a new runtime version.  The CLR, jitter and many of the base assemblies are still v2.0.  The only difference in these later releases are added assemblies.

So the required option is `/targetplatform:v2,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`

Fwiw, do be very, **very** careful when you target .NET 4.x, the c:\windows\microsoft.net directory is no longer the home directory for reference assemblies.  Now located in c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies.  Getting this wrong can cause exceedingly hard to diagnose [runtime errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13750130/17034) when the machine has .NET 4.5+ installed.  And now it *does* matter which specific subdirectory you pick.