# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error on updating NuGet package

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

Hi I have updated Manage NuGet package and my VS 2013 give "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error Whenever I run program. I tried to find solution but failed. So I uninstalled VS and then reinstall. But the error is same even on making new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and was forced to revert to an earlier version of NuGet. v2.8.6 has imposed a dependency on .NET 4.5+ in a point release - bad behavior IMHO. See [NuGet 2.8.6 causing dependency on .NET 4.5+?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31681248/4185948)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tackled this issue in a worst way. I reinstalled my Windows!