# $(TargetedFrameworkDir) incorrectly defined for targetframework 4.5

Tags: visual-studio, .net-4.5

I encounter same issue as below link mentioned,

[TargetedFrameworkDir incorrectly defined for .net 4.5](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/799665/-targetedframeworkdir-incorrectly-defined-for-targetframework-4-5)

it's said it's fixed, however I still have this issue even upgrading to vs2013 update 5.

is this fixed in a separate hotfix or somewhere?

thanks in advance.

kind regards

Comment: It was just added to the bug database, they never promise what specific release will include the bug fix.  Hopefully they'll never do since fixing it [will be worse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13750130/17034).  Never do this.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but how can fix it will be worse? a huge wave of bugs would come?

Comment: Well, worse, bugs that are extremely hard to diagnose.  [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: ok, so we make bugs, and we also depends on them, never fix them!