# Member access call does not compile but static call does

Tags: c#, visual-studio, syntax-checking

So today I faced interesting problem while trying to build our company solution and I wanted to ask you guys do you know why is this happening. I've been told that it might be from my machine/visual studio because other people did not have same problem.

So we have a method in project `A`:

```
private static string RpcRoutingKeyNamingConvention(Type messageType, ITypeNameSerializer typeNameSerializer)
{
   string queueName = typeNameSerializer.Serialize(messageType);

   return messageType.GetAttribute<GlobalRPCRequest>() != null || AvailabilityZone == null
        ? queueName
        : queueName + "_" + AvailabilityZone;
}
```

where `GetAttribute<GlobalRPCRequest>()` is defined in `public static class ReflectionHelpers`

```
 public static TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(this Type type) where TAttribute : Attribute;
```

then we have project `B` which have method:

```
public static string GetAttribute(this XElement node, string name)
{
   var xa = node.Attribute(name);
   return xa != null ? xa.Value : "";
}
```

I have to point out that we have reference to project `B` in project `A`.
Now what happens is that when I try to build I get compile error:

> Error 966 The type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.    D:\Repositories\website\website\submodules\core\src\A\Extensions\Extensions.cs  37  13  A

Whats happening is that compiler thinks that I am actually using `GetAttribute` method from project `B`(in my opinion!). Why this is happening? Since when I try to navigate to `GetAttribute` VS leads me to the right method (the one that is in `ReflectionHelpers`).
Could it be because of the reflection? **NOTE**: I fixed this issue by calling the method statically or adding reference to System.Xml.Linq in my project `A`, but I am curious of the strange behavior of VS/syntax-checking feature.

Comment: Are you referencing the assembly containing XElement? Cuz its telling you _thats_ the problem; no method names mentioned. I mean did you try adding System.xml.linq?

Comment: Yes , I tried this actually fix the problem , but as I said we found the solution of this , but the strange behavior remains and I got curious. Plus adding reference to `System.XML.LINQ` it DOES solve the problem, but it is strange that compiler gets confused before that cause it is obvious(well maybe not that obvious to him) that I do not use any XElements.

Comment: But you do in project B?

Comment: No, I added the reference in project A. Project B was building with no problem.

Comment: Ah. Interesting. Editing what you told me in these comments into the question would greatly clarify for others

Comment: I am not sure but if you say so... its not like I am asking for solution of the error rather than asking for an explanation of the strange behavior. What does it matter how exactly I fixed it?

Comment: ??? It might spark some ones memory idk. I see it as potentially useful; you dont. Its your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35940354/17034

Comment: Thanks man , that was exactly what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

It's a guess, but I think your function:

`private static string RpcRoutingKeyNamingConvention(Type messageType, ITypeNameSerializer typeNameSerializer)` does not match your helper method signature because you try returning a string:

`public static TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(this Type type) where TAttribute : Attribute;` which expects a TAttribute return type.

Maybe, you can try modifiying your function `RpcRoutingKeyNamingConvention` to return `GlobalRPCRequest` and check if the compiler continues to go crazy.

Comment: `does not match your helper method signature because you try returning a string:` what do you mean it doesn't match my helper method because I am trying to return string .. this is outrageous to state?

Comment: @Yann REANAUDIN He is not trying to return a string, look at `? queueName : queueName + "_" + AvailabilityZone;`

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio gets confused all the times! I tried to reproduce the scenario in my VS 2015 (.NET 4.6) and it compiles just fine. I didn't have to add reference to System.Xml.Linq in my Project A.

My guess is that it might be a cache issue. You might want to try this:

1. Remove reference to Project B
2. **Clean** then **rebuild** both solutions
3. Add the reference back
4. Rebuild and voila!! Well.. hopefully

Hope it helps, let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's going on:
- B has reference to System.Xml.Linq
- B is built without a problem.
- You are referencing B in A
- A hasn't got a reference to System.Xml.Linq
- A seem to consume the function defined in B
- When you try to build project A, it produces that error

Am I right?

If that's the case, it is totally normal. Because a project which consumes a reference (A) must have a reference to what is referenced (System.Xml.Linq) by what it references (B).

Think like this: When you try to add a nuget package to your project if it has a dependency, nuget will install it too. Why? Because of this situation.

This is completely normal if I understand your answer correctly.

Comment: The question was why the compiler get confused that it will use function in project B when the navigation of visual studio clearly knows which one is the right method(the one in project A) ? When you answer this answer you will find answer to the original post answer at least that's how I got it. Check out the link in the comments below my question it pretty much answer all I am asking and wondering.

Comment: hahaha! sorry about my poor english (both for my answer and my confusion). You had right to do that :-)

Comment: By the way, which version of vs you are using?

Comment: do you have both versions namespaces in using block? did you try to call the method by providing the whole path? (ex: A.ReflectionHelpers.GetAttribute)

Comment: Yes , I fixed the confusion of compiler with providing the whole path(a.k.a calling it statically.) The question is about the confusion not how to solve it.