# Moving from VS 2010 to 2015, C++/CLI class denoted with [Extension] fails to build, error C2337: 'Extension' : attribute not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

In the header file, Encrypt.h, I have the following:

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace NSpace
{
    namespace Encryption
    {
        [System::Runtime::CompilerServices::Extension]
        public ref class EncryptionExtensions abstract sealed
        {
        public:
            [System::Runtime::CompilerServices::Extension]
            static String^ ExtractEncrypt(String^ value, int length)
            {
                return value->Substring(0, length);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In a VS 2015 project that I set up for testing, this builds without errors or warnings. In my original project, ported from VS 2010, above will not build:
error C2337: 'Extension' : attribute not found
error C2337: 'Extension' : attribute not found
error C2337: 'Extension' : attribute not found
error C2337: 'Extension' : attribute not found

Note two errors for each offending use of [Extension].

The project is C++/CLI (Properties->General->Common Language Runtime Support is set (/clr)). The Platform Toolset is Windows7.1SDK - the test project started out with "Visual Studio 2015 (v140)", but I changed it to emulate the failing project, and it didn't make any difference in the test project, it still builds.

The project Properties->C/C++->General->Common Language Runtime Support is also set (/clr).

The original build environment is VS 2010, version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel. The original and ported projects are both targeting .Net 4.0 (for C# projects).

Any ideas why this won't build (in the original project)?

Comment: I'm building on Windows 7, 64-bit OS, 32-bit build (for C++).

Comment: You are, somehow, using old reference assemblies.  Programmers went pretty nutty at VS2010 to try to build projects to target .NET 3.5.  That cannot work, the C++/CLI runtime always targets .NET 4 and still building for older runtimes requires using VS2008.  Open the .vcxproj files in Notepad and compare, crystal ball says that there is a stray `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` element in the one that doesn't build.

Comment: The <TargetFrameworkVersion> is set to "v4.0". However, when I set the <TargetFrameworkVersion> in my test project to "v4.0" (it was "v4.5.2"), and rebuild, it fails with identical errors.

Comment: Setting the <TargetFrameworkVersion> to "v4.5.2" causes the build to complete with no errors.

Comment: If that works then you probably have a different problem, it is very nasty.  You must use the [correct reference assemblies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13750130/17034).