# Compiler warning C4945

Tags: c++-cli, clr

I am trying to compile a simple CLR project, which has no dependency.

When I compile this project I get 973 warnings (C4945) stating that

```
c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\system.dll : warning C4945: 'xxx' : cannot import symbol from 'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\system.dll': as 'xxx' has already been imported from another assembly 'System'
```

As I mentioned that my project has no dependency on other projects, I tried to compile my cpp files one by one, starting with stdafx.cpp.

While doing this I noticed that if I include `#include <msclr\marshal.h>` I get those warnings, and if I don't there are no warnings.

Now I have following queries.

1. Is `#include <msclr\marshal.h>` deprecated and replaced by something
   else?
2. If no, how can I remove those warnings? Is #pragma warning disable the only way?

Comment: Show us the code for a minimum reproducible sample!

Comment: Create a new CLR project using Visual Studio 2012.
`File -> New Project -> CLR -> Class Library`

In the `stdafx.h` include `#include <msclr\marshal.h>` and compile it.

Let me know, if this helps or let me know how can i share a sample

Comment: I have only VS-2015 and I can't reproduce this. No errors no warnings.

Comment: Can you change the Platform Toolset in Project Properties and check it?

Comment: No. I don' t have this toolset installed. Even setting the toolset to VS-2013 (the oldest one I have installed) shows no warnings or errors.

Comment: Thank You @xMRi. Appreciate your efforts, may be someone else can help. :)

Comment: Marshal.h is but the canary in the coal mine, it contains a `#using <System.dll>` directive.  These reference assemblies must come from c:\program files\reference assembles, not from c:\windows\microsoft.net.  So the compiler is using the wrong `/AI` option.  That's a pretty critical problem, using the wrong reference assemblies can cause [very nasty runtime problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748055/could-not-load-type-system-runtime-compilerservices-extensionattribute-from-as).  I only remember that VS2012 was prone to this problem, not something I can check anymore.

Comment: @hans so what do you suggest?

Comment: Keep your VS version updated so people can help you.

Comment: I would have, if I was the decision maker. I work for my bosses. Think I will have to deal with this.

Comment: @HansPassant: On the other hand, should I use something else to convert between different strings in CLR other than marshal?

Answer (score 0):

This is still a problem for VS2019, but you can force the header to skip `#using <System.dll>` like this:

```
#pragma push_macro("_CRT_WINDOWS")
#define _CRT_WINDOWS
#include <msclr\marshal.h>
#pragma pop_macro("_CRT_WINDOWS")
```

This works for the other marshal headers as well (`marshal_cppstd.h`, etc.)