# .NET 4 to .NET 4.5.2 - PresentationFramework 'Method 'get_Command'

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Error   251 Unknown build error, 'Method 'get_Command' in type 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.RepeatButton' from assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. Line 1 Position 340.'

I upgraded from .net 4 to .net 4.5.2 in a WPF application and now all the pages are throwing the error above. I have tried to perform a clean, close the application, then reopen and build but no go. Also ensured that the version that the PresentationFramework is pointing to is 4.5.2. Actual version number is: 4.0.30319.34211

Anyone deal with this before?

Comment: ICommand was moved in 4.5, probably has something to do with it.  [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13750130/17034)

Comment: @HansPassant not sure i see it from the read.... very frustrating