# Installing VS 2015 Community edition makes VS 2013 to throw errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have downloaded and installed the free Community Edition of VS 2015 from Microsoft. After the install, I am unable to use VS 2013 Professional, which was working fine before the install. The start page shows, "Content Load Error". The solution explorer shows the following errors:
An exception was encountered while constructing the content of this frame.  This information is also logged in "C:\Users\VeluMain\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml".

Exception details:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsShell5.LoadPackageWithContext(Guid& packageGuid, Int32 reason, Guid& context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.GetPackage()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()

I searched in Google, but couldn't find any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that one of your plugins for VS2013 has been broken by the VS2015 installer. For example I had an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533739/autofixture-cannot-create-claim-with-net-framework-4-6) where VS2015 installer also installed .NET Framework 4.6 which alters the .NET Framework 4.5.1 DLLs, I guess there's a chance it could be the same kind of thing...

Try running VS2013 in [Safe Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278(v=vs.120).aspx) (i.e. without plugins). If this works fine then you know it's one of your plugins that is causing the issue, you should then use a process of elimination to determine which one is the culprit. If it doesn't work then you might want to reinstall VS2013.